# Python recursive function doesn't return anything what to do

Tags: python, recursion

hi I wrote the code below, i was expecting the function to return 8 but somehow this function doesn't return any value at all, is there a way to modify this function so it can return some value? (please still use a recursive function). Also it would be much appreciated if you can let me know why this problem occurred.

Thanks!

```
 def recursive(left):
    if left<=7:
        left+=1
        recursive(left)
                      
    else:
        return left

recursive(0)
```

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: You are missing `return` when calling `recursion` on line 4.

Comment: return recursive(left)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the function you should use the return to get the result back to the called function.

```
def recursive(left):
    if left<=7:
        left+=1
        return recursive(left)
                      
    else:
        return left
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
def recursive(left):
    if left<=7:
        left+=1
        return recursive(left)
                      
    else:
        return left

recursive(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `recursive(left)` the function ends, so it has an implicit `return None` there.